# Rails 4, undefined method `rescue_action_in_public'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, undefined, rescue

So I'm trying to do an alias_method on :rescue_action_in_public within a module, included in my controller, when an exception is raised, but I keep getting "undefined method `rescue_action_in_public' from FooController".

This is my module:

```
module DoSomethingToExceptions
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    alias_method :rescue_action_in_public_with_some_extra_thing, :rescue_action_in_public
    alias_method :rescue_action_in_public, :rescue_action_in_public_without_some_extra_thing
  end

  def rescue_action_in_public_with_some_extra_thing
    do_something
    rescue_action_in_public_without_some_extra_thing
  end
end
```

For testing this, I have a `before_filter` in my controller that calls a method that only does `raise 'FooException'`, just to get rescue_action_in_public called. Beside that, and including this module, that's the relevant controller code involved.

I have really tried to understand how this is supposed to work. The way I assumed this would work is, `rescue_action_in_public` gets called "from rails" when an exception is raised, and since I'm then aliasing this method, my alias method is called instead, doing whatever it is I want to add to that process, and then I'm telling it to do `rescue_action_in_public_without_some_extra_thing`, which is then aliased to the original `rescue_action_in_public`, so the native rails process should then go on.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`rescue_action_in_public` is no longer part of the Rails API. Based on http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Rescue/rescue_action_in_public it existed in Rails 1.x and 2.x, but was removed in Rails 3.0.

The closest equivalent in Rails 4 is probably `rescue_from`, but it's meant to rescue from specific exceptions, not all exceptions.